# Changing values of a cell in a datagrid depending on a number

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to change the numbers inside a grid into a text. Depending on the value in the cell I should get another text.
If the `value = 0` it should show `"inkomst"` and if the `value = 1` it should show `"Uitgave"`.

I already have this code to display the correct rows and to format the widths.

```
private void updateAll()
{
    dataGridViewInkomsten.DataSource = blFinancien.getFinancienByInkomsten();

    //kolommen niet tonen waarin enkel id's worden getoond
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[1].Visible = false;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[2].Visible = false;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[8].Visible = false;

    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Inkomst/uitgave";

    int breedtevankolommen = dataGridViewInkomsten.Width / 5;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[3].Width = breedtevankolommen;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[4].Width = breedtevankolommen;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[5].Width = breedtevankolommen;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[6].Width = breedtevankolommen;
    dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[7].Width = breedtevankolommen;
}
```

Now depending on the int value in the sixth column I should get `"Inkomst"` or `"Uitgave"`.
I also got a printscreen, so you see what I mean.

[image: datagrid]

Could anybody tell me how to get that done?

Comment: when you are saving the record in db then check the textbox's value if it is 0 then store Inkmost in db.. thats all i think there is nothing to ask.. it is basic thing

Comment: Side not: you should code in English, even if you're writing a dutch program.

Comment: Toon: I'm not allowed by my teacher, thats why, but yeah the most is readable, even if you don't know Dutch.
Raman: It should be stored in ints, way safer & by the rules :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create cell style:

```
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
 dataGridViewCellStyle1.Format = "One;\'\';Zero";
 dataGridViewCellStyle1.NullValue = null;
```

Than apply the cell style to your dynamic column:

```
 dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[6].DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

That should do it.

Comment: Great solution, did it exactly as I wanted!
Thanks for helping me for like two hours man!

Answer (score 0):

edit you query through which you are binding your grid.

**include case when in it as follows:**

```
CASE WHEN lnkomst/uitgave = 0 THEN 'lnkomst' ELSE 'uitgave' END

select col1,col2,(CASE WHEN lnkomst/uitgave = 0 THEN 'lnkomst' ELSE 'uitgave' END) as lnkomst/uitgave  from tablename
```

write query like this.

**Edit for access:**

```
select col1,col2,lnkomst/uitgave = Switch(
    NUMREG=0,'lnkomst',
    NUMREG=1,'uitgave');  from tablename
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you referring to writing this in the SQL? I'm using BLL and DAL 
And this is my code to get everything in the SQL part:
select * from financien

Comment: Freelancer: Sadly my SQL version (it uses access as a local db in combination with C#) does not support this :/

Answer (score 0):

After you save the data into the DB, use 
datagridview.rows[].cells[].value

Comment: Pretty nice, but I sadly don't know how many cells there will be, so how can I give it a value in cells[] then? :/
I only have this:
dataGridViewInkomsten.DataSource = blFinancien.getAlleFinancien();
 //kolommen niet tonen waarin enkel id's worden getoond
dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[0].Visible = false;
dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[1].Visible = false;
dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[2].Visible = false;
dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[8].Visible = false;

dataGridViewInkomsten.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Inkomst/uitgave";

Comment: Then you could try counting all records in the database, the with a for loop check each value in the gridview, and put the for counter into cells[]

Comment: aantal = blFinancien.getAlleFinancien().Count();
int teller;
            for (teller = 0; teller <= aantal; teller++)
            {
                if (dataGridViewInkomsten.Rows[6].Cells[teller].Value == "0")
                {
                    dataGridViewInkomsten.CurrentCell.Value = "Inkomst";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridViewInkomsten.CurrentCell.Value = "Uitgave";
                }
            }
I did this, but sadly he doesn't change anything when I open my programme / datagrid? :/

Comment: Is it "0" as a string or just a plain int 0 in your DB?

Comment: Its an int value, so databasefield is an int with the value '0' or '1'

Comment: dataGridViewInkomsten.CurrentCell - instead of this, use dataGridViewInkomsten.Rows[6].Cells[teller].Value

Comment: if (dataGridViewInkomsten.CurrentCell.Value == "0")
You ment like this right? Because that doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.

1. You can write a switch case in you SQL query and set the required text.
2. Or you can add another column in your grid. Say COLUMN2. Hide the actual column say COLUMN1.
   Then in you grid cell formatting event (or any similar event) you can set the text of this column (COLUMN2) based on the value in the actual column (COLUMN1).

   private sub grid_CellFormatting(sender ,e)
   {
       if(grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLUMN1").Text == "0")
           grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLUMN2").text = "value1"
       else(grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLUMN1").Text == "1")
           grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("COLUMN2").text = "value2"
   }
3. Actually you should be doing this kind of formatting for UI in your domain model and then bind you domain model to your grid. That is after you have fetched the data from database.

Comment: Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Rows' cannot be used like a method. 
is the error message I'm getting :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("connString");
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable";
var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

for (int i = 0; i <= int.Parse(count.ToString()); i++)
{
     if (dataGridViewCategories.Rows[i].Cells["cellName"].Value.ToString() == "0")
     {
        dataGridViewCategories.Rows[i].Cells["coulmnName"].Value = "Inkomst";
     }
     else
     {
        dataGridViewCategories.Rows[i].Cells["coulmnName"].Value = "Uitgave";
     }
}
```